# Installing Ubuntu on a USB drive from ISO image

Tags: software-installation

I have windows 10 and have downloaded the Ubuntu Desktop version to use on a separate older system. Is there a special program I need to install the iso on my USB drive and make it installs on start up?

Comment: Is your Windows 10 BIOS or UEFI? If upgrade from Windows 7 probably BIOS. If originally Windows 8 or 10 from vendor then it will be UEFI as Microsoft requires UEFI for new installs. Simple way to create installer for UEFI only: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media And be sure to boot installer in same boot mode as Windows is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this program: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.7.exe

People usually have the best success with it.